# Storing data(java object) in couchbase

Tags: java, mysql, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

We are converting our, java + MySql application to [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/), for that we are using spring-data and a couchbase server.

I am confused how the Java objects(Entity / POJO) needs to be saved on to the couchbase bucket.

I read that, i can't create one bucket per Entity, So shall i put all data on to one bucket and add a **_class** property so that i can identify the data bjects ?

Is that the right way? Please share any links or suggestions about the same.

[Spring data with couchbase](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/), This is the link i was using.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the correct way but I have a type field that I added to all my POJOs with their class path (eg com.companyname.appname.test). Depending on what you're doing though couch may not be the best solution. It's not meant to replace a SQL based system. So if you have a handful of classes it may not be too bad. But you'll have a difficult time enforcing a large schema in a system that is supposed to be relatively schema-less.

Answer (score 2):

if you create objects through Spring Data Couchbase, they will automatically have this _class property. It is use by Spring Data to convert the Json object from Couchbase to a POJO. Using a type field (or the _class field added automatically by Spring Data)is indeed a good practice as it allows you to filter easily when creating views or using N1QL. Which is also how you will find objects of different types in the same bucket.